# How to get array item without looping in android?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an String array with multiple items.

```
String[] folder={"proc","root","sdcard","cache","system","config","dev","sys","acct","sbin","etc"};
```

Now I want to check in if condition like

```
if(list[i].getName().equals(object))
```

Is there any method that can check whole array and if list[i] present in array then go into the if condition block.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For instance:

```
Arrays.asList(folder).contains("sdcard");
```

- `asList`: Returns a List of the objects in the specified array.
- `contains`: Tests whether this List contains the specified object.

Comment: I think he need to check .getName() not if the array contains an item